# How to convert unicode characters into their respective symbols in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a text file which contains unicode characters in the following format:

```
\u0935\u094d\u0926\u094d\u0928\u094d\u0935\u094d\u0926\
```

I want to convert it into devnagri characters in the following format:

```
वर्जनरूपमिति दर्शित्म् । स पूरुषः अमृतत्वाय कल्पते व्द्न्व्द
```

and then write it to a file.
Presently my code

```
encoded = x.encode('utf-8')
print (encoded.decode('unicode-escape'))
```

can print the devnagri characters in the terminal. However when I try to write it to a file using

```
text = 'target:'+encoded.decode('unicode-escape')+'\n'
fileid.write(text)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: How did you open the file?

Comment: i opened it using `fileid = open('compare.txt','a')`

Comment: I think you might need to look at the `codecs` library.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: Write `str` objects to the file instead of `unicode`.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this @Goyo. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "Write str objects to the file instead of unicode".

Comment: First and foremost add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python 2 it's because after using `.decode('unicode-escape')` you have an `unicode` object and `fileid.write()` only accepts string objects. Python then tries to convert the object to a byte string by using the ASCII encoding that doesn't cover devnagri characters. This conversion causes the exception.

You need to manually convert the unicode string back into a byte string before writing it to the file:

```
fileid.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Here I assumed you want UTF-8 encoding. If you want to save the characters in another encoding replace `'utf-8'` with the name of that encoding.

In Python 3 you can set the used encoding when opening the file:

```
fileid = open('compare.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
```

Then the extra `.encode('utf-8')` isn't neccessary.

Comment: Solved!! Thanks a lot @cg909. You explanation was very helpful.

Comment: In Python 2 the `io` library has the same `open` implementation as Python 3.  Use `io.open('compare.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')`.  Then no need to maunally convert the Unicode string back to bytes.